# WPF listbox alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am pulling some data from DB, and I would like to have that data in some kind of columns aligned along the listbox, but I keep getting elements next to each other.

What I have:

```
el1 el1
longEl2 longEl2
```

What I want

```
el1       el1
longEl2   longEl2
```

Code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding lb}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}"/>

                <TextBlock Margin="10" Grid.Column="1">test</TextBlock>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: ColumnDefinition width=SomeValue might help you. or you can make your grid adn listbox `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` so that it takes all the spaces in equal sizes

Comment: Already tried it...it is recalculating again for each element loaded

Comment: Still the same...stretch doesn't seem to do anything, width also

Comment: How about stretch horizontant content alignment on the listbox as well as strech

Comment: @Norgul: `Stretch` for both ListBox and Grid would do and yeah `horizontantcontentalignment` also set to strech

Comment: Oh...sorry, was using `HorizontalAlignment` ...it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

With ListBox or generally every ItemsControl to contain Grids internally for every row and make the grid columns equal in each row you can use the [SharedSizeScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604402/how-to-align-separate-grids-created-via-templates-along-their-columns-rows). You define `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on the control and name the grid columns with `SharedSizeGroup="ColumnName"` in the data template.